# MySQL How can I create a dynamic result of numbers grouped by an "upto" value with a count

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I'm looking to group a set of numbers by an "upto" value and show a count of how many results are up to this value omitting any zeros

e.g. data could be
38600,
46526,
35813,
26629,
36127,
38196,
21006,
21375,
14867,
32187,
26498,
13506,
62730,
31187,
23876,
45946,
54845,
48000,
50000,
36783

And the result would be

```
+-----+-----+
|upto |count|
+-----+-----+
|15000|2    |
|25000|5    |
|30000|7    |
|35000|9    |
|40000|14   |
|50000|18   |
|60000|19   |
|70000|20   |
+-----+-----+
```

I've got as far as

```
SELECT
       (CASE
        WHEN `value` < 100 THEN 100
        WHEN `value` BETWEEN 100 AND 500 THEN 500
        WHEN `value` BETWEEN 500 AND 50000 THEN (CEIL(`value` / 5000) * 5000)
        WHEN `value` BETWEEN 50000 AND 100000 THEN (CEIL(`value`) / 10000) * 10000)
        WHEN `value` BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000 THEN (CEIL(`value`) / 25000) * 25000)
        WHEN `value` BETWEEN 200000 AND 500000 THEN (CEIL(`value`) / 50000) * 50000)
        WHEN `value` > 500000 THEN (CEIL(`value`) / 100000) * 100000)
END) as `upto`, 
COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM table
GROUP BY `upto`;
```

Which gives the following

```
+-----+-----+
|upto |count|
+-----+-----+
|15000|2    |
|25000|3    |
|30000|2    |
|35000|2    |
|40000|5    |
|50000|4    |
|60000|1    |
|70000|1    |
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?  But a running total is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You need in something like

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(upto, 'Total') upper_border, SUM(value <= upto)
FROM data
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 100 upto UNION ALL
             SELECT 1000 UNION ALL
             SELECT 10000 ) upper_value
GROUP BY upto WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY upper_border;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=423260ccc05b1c12a7030e297764461b